# Redirect route to a totally new one with same domain Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

The website with this route `Domain.tld/faq.php=?lang=en&id=121` need to redirect to `Domain.tld/some/121?lang=en` not only `id=121` but any id with the old route to be redirected to the new route.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. What have you tried so far?